# Noise bound in FHE over the integers

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm studying the paper [*Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integers*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616.pdf) by Marten van Dijk, Craig Gentry, Shai Halevi and Vinod Vaikuntanathan.

I have questions about the proof of Lemma A.1.

In page 6, the element of public key is in the form of $x=pq+r$
and the encryption is 
$$ c← [m+2r+2\sum x_i]_{x_0} $$

But in the proof of Lemma A.1., the public key is $x=pq+2r$
and the encryption is 
$$ c← [m+2r+\sum x_i]_{x_0} $$

This problem made me confused.
I tried to proof with first definition, but I encounter with another problem.
When I follow the same flow of the proof with first definition,
I reached that the noise term is $$(m+2r+k*r_0+ \sum 2r_i )$$
What I need to next is to get the upper bound of a $|m+2r+k\cdot r_0+ \sum 2r_i|$.
So I got
$$|m+2r+k*r_0+ \sum 2r_i| \leq m+2\cdot2^{\rho\prime} + \tau \cdot 2^{\rho}+\tau \cdot 2^{\rho} =m+2\cdot2^{\rho\prime} +2 \tau2^{\rho}$$

If the definition of permitted circuit in this thesis is correct, at least
$$m+2\cdot2^{\rho\prime} +2 \tau2^{\rho} \leq 2^{\rho \prime +2}$$
should be satisfied.

Can anybody help to get upper bound of noise?

### Original question

I'm reading https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616.pdf

I am reading the proof of Lemma A.1 which is in page 21.

In the page 22, the thesis tells that the noise is at most $(4\tau + 3)2^\rho < \tau2^{
\rho+3}$.

But I cannot follow the inequality.

Could you guys help me to understand the proof of Lemma A.1?

Comment: Has someone managed to prove the estimation of $|m+2b|$? I don't even see why $|k| \leq \tau$. And even if this were true, I dont see how one can reach $(4\tau+3)2^\rho$ following JongHyun Kim's estimation, since we would have to bound the term containing $2^{\rho'}$.

Answer (score 2):

Just expand it out.  You get $4\tau \cdot 2^\rho + 3 \cdot 2^\rho$.  Then,

$\tau \cdot 4 \cdot 2^\rho = \tau \cdot 2^2 \cdot 2^\rho = \tau \cdot 2^{\rho + 2}$

and

$3\cdot 2^\rho < 4 \cdot 2^\rho = 2^{\rho+2}$.

Put it back together,

$\tau \cdot 2^{\rho + 2} + 2^{\rho + 2} < \tau (2^{\rho + 2}+2^{\rho + 2}) = \tau 2^{\rho+3}$

Comment: Oh, Actually, I fail to achieve (4τ+3)2^ρ.
the noise is m+2r+k*r_0+sigma(2r_i).
When we use triangle inequality, 2r term becomes 2*2^ρ'.
the point is that i cannot change  2*2^ρ' terms into some polynomials of 2^ρ

Comment: @JongHyunKim, please don't use comments to ask a new question.  Comments should only be used to help the author of the answer improve their answer.  (This is not a discussion forum; see the [faq] for more details on how to use this site.)

Comment: Ok. I will modify my Question.